# How do I auto select an input field when I load a page?

Tags: javascript, html

How do some sites automatically select a input field when you enter a page? Like YouTube's login page it selects the Username field automatically

This site too, on page Ask Question for example, it selects the Title field.

How do they do this? My guess would be javascript

But how?

Comment: @Daniel Moralea: Just a note, the action you are referring to is known as focus. Selection is a different beast.

Answer (score 2):

```
<head>
<!-- set focus to a field with the name "searchcontent" in my form -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setfocus(a_field_id) {
        $(a_field_id).focus()
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="setfocus('customervalue');">

Customer: <input name="customer" id="customervalue" />

</body>
```

From here: http://lena.franken.de/software/javascript/index.html

Answer (score 2):

In The Future: `<input type="text" autofocus>` :-)

Not a good idea to use onload on body either, use an onDomReady-event, for instance from YUI or jQuery or some custom script instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

someObject.focus()

Reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/met_anchor_focus.asp

Answer (score 1):

Most sites currently do this with JavaScript autofocusers, as given in other answers here. But if you're thinking of implementing similar behaviour, be aware that this can be annoying for some users due to the way the JavaScript works. For example, if you focus a different field while a page is still loading, the JavaScript may "help" you by moving the focus and making you type in the wrong field. [This question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/2861/2530) on ui.stackexchange.com enumerates some more drawbacks.

To prevent this, HTML5 has introduced an [`autofocus` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control) for form elements that means the behaviour will be consistently implemented by the browser itself, and can be turned off for users that find it irritating. Of course, this isn't supported by all browsers yet. For more info, see the section on [autofocus fields](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#autofocus) in Mark Pilgrim's excellent [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/) book.